# XMLunit compare only tags

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xmlunit

I would like to compare two XML files, but based only on tag values, also I need to compare tags as a whole, e.g.

`<someTag><otherTag value1="0" value2="5"/>text1</someTag>`

`<someTag><otherTag value1="10" value2="15"/>text2</someTag>`

what I need to achieve is to show that `<otherTag value1="10" value2="15"/>` is different, I don't care about `text1` `text2` difference. Problem is, that by default XMLUnit will compare `value1` and `value2` separetly, while I want to compare them together, whole tag as one string. Is there a way to achieve this? I know I can exclude `text` implementing `DifferenceEvaluator` but still, I don't know how to compare Attributes as whole. I also consider to use xslt.

Answer (score 0):

I would transform both documents to get rid of the things you want to exclude from the comparison, and then compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can chain the DifferenceEvaluators together to achieve this.

For example, this is something I did when I had to combine comparison for two nodes. Might work in your case with some customisations.

```java
Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(FileReadingUtil.readFileAsByteArray(source,this.getClass().getClassLoader()))
                .withTest(FileReadingUtil.readFileAsByteArray(test,this.getClass().getClassLoader()))
                .ignoreComments()
                .ignoreWhitespace()
                .withDifferenceEvaluator(
                        DifferenceEvaluators.chain(
                                DifferenceEvaluators.Default,
                                new IgnoreAttributeDifferenceEvaluator("MsgId"),
                                new IgnoreAttributeDifferenceEvaluator("PmtId")
                        )
                )
                .checkForSimilar()
                .build();
```